# vim line operations (e.g., dd) on wrapped text

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I'm using wrap in vim, but I want vim to otherwise behave as though the lines have actual breaks in them (rather than "soft breaks" for screen rendering).

I've mapped j to gj and k to gk for navigation. However, line operations (such as dd) still act upon the whole line, rather than the "screen line". Is there any way to alter this behavior such that 'dd' is limited to the screen line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585763/vim-delete-display-lines-instead-of-physical-lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a key mapping:

```
:nnoremap dd g0dg$
```

Answer (score 4):

I would rather create a new operator, for example `x` in operator-pending mode:

```
onoremap x :norm! g0vg$<cr>
xnoremap x g$og0o
```

With the first mapping, `dx` will delete a screen line, `yx` will yank a screen line (beware, it will not be pasted linewise, but characterwise), `cx` will delete a screen line and start insert mode, and so on.

With the 2nd mapping, `x` in visual mode will extend to screen lines the visual selection.

I wouldn't advise remapping dd, because this might break plugins (if they use `:normal` instead of `:normal!` or if they use `:×××map` instead of `:×××noremap`.